# Is it possible to develop the line charts with multiple colors in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, linechart

I developed the few Line charts for BMP280 sensor data in powerbi. This is one of the line chart for displaying the temperature value by time and device id.

[image]
But I want same line chart with different Color like this below image, whenever temperature value suddenly changes.

[image]
Can you please tell me is it possible to develop the Line chart with multiple colors?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to consider a vertical bar chart instead of a line chart, you would be able to create a calculation for each row that determines whether the change is significant, potentially by comparing an aggregate of recent measurements to specific thresholds.

Once you do that, you would use this column's value as a legend for your visualization. So if a row has a value of "Significant Positive Change" (or something like that), the bar or bars showing that change can be red.

Your other alternative is to use an R-based visual, of which there are surely examples of this type of visualization. I'll update this answer if I find one that looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tending 1 data series, you can split it into 2 data series e.g. one with normal temperatures and one with high temperatures. Then you can just plot these in different colours. Just make sure that the ranges are same i.e. cannot be 'Auto'.